# How to make clone a part of my scene in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using a script to create a very large scene. Using that code I am generating a lot of new game objects, or in other words clones.

How can I save them and make this new object a constant part of my game scene?

Comment: Copy-and-Paste usually. You can copy them when the game is in "run" mode and then after exiting run mode you can hit "paste" and they'll stick around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that there is a way to save an object as part of a scene in code, but in runtime you can right-click on a clone, click "Copy" (or CTRL+C or CMD+C), and then once you exit runtime you can right-click on the scene hierarchy and click "Paste" (or CTRL+V or CMD+V) - this will paste the clone as a constant object in the scene.

If you want to save many objects at once in the scene, I recommend combining them all into an empty game object if you haven't already, selecting them all (click on one end of the list and while holding down shift click the other end), copying, and then pasting once you exit runtime.